# How to slide up when click any outside of div?

Tags: jquery

I have made a toggle slide menu with jquery mobile
And how to slides back up when click anywhere of div?

this is my jquery script here

```
<script>  
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.gnbLayer').hide();
            $(".icGnb5").click(function () {
                $(this).toggleClass("on");
                 $('.gnbLayer').slideToggle('medium');

            }); 
        }); 
        </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
$(document).click(function(){
 $('.gnbLayer').slideUp();
});
```

also modify click event to stoppropogation:

```
$(".icGnb5").click(function (e) {
             $(this).toggleClass("on");
             $('.gnbLayer').slideToggle('medium');
             e.stopPropagation();

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this,

```
  $(document).click(function(){
      $(".icGnb5").toggleClass("off");
      $('.gnbLayer').slideUp();
  });
```